# Using asciimath syntax or equivalent in latex

Tags: math-mode, packages

Recently I have been using a program called [caoutchouc](https://caoutchouc.io/) which allows me to write latex with ease, by integrating the [asciimath](http://asciimath.org/) syntax.

TLDR it allows you to write somthing like this `sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n(n+1))/2)^2` and it simply get's formatted as we would want, like so:

[image]

I am wondering if something like that exists in latex that would allow me to take advantage of the asciimath syntax or equivalently simple syntax for writing math.

Comment: If you give it an opportunity, ConTeXt, another format based on TeX, has asciimath support integrated: http://www.pragma-pod.nl/general/manuals/mmlprime.pdf

Comment: you can use a pre-processor such as the one you found, but the latex `\sum_{i=1}^n i^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2` is hardly more complicated than the asciimath, and is a lot more flexible in choice of available commands

Answer (score 4):

ConTeXt has `asciimath` support, to use it in a document you have to load a module first.

To insert a formula pass the code as argument to the `\asciimath` command.

```
\usemodule[asciimath]

\starttext

\startformula
\asciimath{sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n(n+1))/2)^2}
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

[image]